# Mysql Check in two tables if the value is included in an array of the other table

Tags: mysql

[Screenshot of DBB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRv7X.png)

I need to get rows from first_table if First_table.id is include in Second_table.programAllowed.

Thanks a lot

Comment: what field type for you second table ```programAllowed``` column

Comment: It's a string where i stock a stringify array

Comment: The second table has multiple rows.Do you want to get allowed program specific second table row or whole ?